# Symfony showing error when setting Up an old Project "vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php on line 243"

Tags: php, symfony, runtime-error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! in /home/dev707/project/project-folders/live/vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php on line 243
( ! ) Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! in /home/dev707/project/project-folders/live/vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php on line 243
```

When setting an old symfony project almost 5-6 years old , im facing this issue.

this is my composer.json

```
    {
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php",
      "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.7",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.0",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "symfony/debug": "^3.1",
    "ddeboer/data-import": "dev-master",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
    "lexik/translation-bundle": "~4.0.1",
    "ibrows/sonata-translation-bundle": "dev-master",
    "kms/froala-editor-bundle": "dev-master",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^4.0",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.4",
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^1.4",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "^2.1",
    "webfactory/exceptions-bundle": "@stable",
    "shapecode/cron-bundle": "^2.1.0",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3.2",
    "twilio/sdk": "^5.7",
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.3"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "5.5.9"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my prod.log

```
[2019-10-18 17:14:57] request.INFO: Matched route "sonata_admin_dashboard". {"route":"sonata_admin_dashboard","route_parameters":{"_controller":"Pekko\\CoreBundle\\Controller\\DashboardController::dashboardAction","_route":"sonata_admin_dashboard"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/project-folders/live/web/app.php/dashboard","method":"GET"} []
[2019-10-18 17:14:57] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2019-10-18 17:14:57] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"rony.james@domaintech.com","provider":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\EmailUserProvider"} []
[2019-10-18 17:14:57] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!" at /home/dev707/project/project-folders/live/src/Pekko/OrganisationBundle/Entity/Organisation.php line 117 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting! at /home/dev707/project/project-folders/live/src/Pekko/OrganisationBundle/Entity/Organisation.php:117)"} []
```

As per my references, the project was developed almost 5-6 years ago, the application built on Symfony 3.1 framework with Composer for PHP package control primarily extending the Sonata Admin bundle to create an interactive dashboard console.
This application works similar to a SaaS console-setup, a data belonging and limited to a specific organization.

```
Im actually a laravel developer , im not so familear with symfony.

Here i got this project through FTP with Composer so
1) Extracted and set it up in my local.
2)Change the permissions of the "app/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
Change the permissions of the "app/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it. 

3)Changed DB configuration and used  php bin/console doctrine:database:create
4)then imported the SQL DB.


Is there any step Missing
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop somewhere. You'll have to track down where two different bits of code are calling each other.

Comment: what's your version of `php`? `php -v`?

Comment: PHP 7.1.32-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2019 13:28:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.32-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans

Comment: Not that I see. As I said, you'll have to track it down. The line referenced are `/home/dev707/project/project-folders/live/src/Pekko/OrganisationBundle/Entity/Organisation.php line 117`, so start there and also in  `sonata_admin_dashboard` to see where the loop might be

Answer (score 0):

You are using `php 7.1`, You have to change `PHP` version `php 7.1` to `php 5.5`

Comment: No php 5.5.9 is the minimum requirement. And even if i use php5.6 bin/console server:run  , Iam still getting this issue

Comment: `Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached ` is from `php version`

Comment: Ok but the issue here is that the project is working fine in live server.

i Just copied it to my local using FTP. Iam having php version as LIVE ,in this case the project should run fine right?

Comment: @ArunP  What version of php is running on the live server?  I'm guessing it is 5.x something.  There were some bc changes between 5 and 7.  Normally you would do a composer update to get past the issues.  Maybe you could try updating your question with some code from Organisation.php but I doubt that will help.  But your best bet might be setup some docker sort of development environment that matches your production server exactly.